# Instantiate multiple spring boot apps in test

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, testing, spring-boot

I have several instances of my spring boot app, which in parallel do some work with DB. Each instance is running in separate JVM.
Is it a way to write a test in Java for testing that on one JVM? Like following:

1. Setup some embedded DB for testing purposes or even just mock it.
2. Start 2-5 instances of my Spring boot app
3. Wait some time
4. Stop all started instances
5. Verify DB and check that all the conditions are met.

Each instance has its own context and classpath. 
I think that I could achieve that with some shell script scenario but I'd like to make it in Java.
What would be the best approach here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can run them multiple times using different ports.

I did something similar

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class ServicesIntegrationTest {

    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    @Test
    public void runTest() throws Exception {
        SpringApplicationBuilder uws = new SpringApplicationBuilder(UserWebApplication.class)
                .properties("server.port=8081",
                        "server.contextPath=/UserService",
                        "SOA.ControllerFactory.enforceProxyCreation=true");
        uws.run();

        SpringApplicationBuilder pws = new SpringApplicationBuilder(ProjectWebApplication.class)
                .properties("server.port=8082",
                        "server.contextPath=/ProjectService",
                        "SOA.ControllerFactory.enforceProxyCreation=true");
        pws.run();

        String url = "http://localhost:8081/UserService/users";
        ResponseEntity<SimplePage<UserDTO>> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                url,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                null,
                new ParameterizedTypeReference<SimplePage<UserDTO>>() {
                });
```

[here](https://github.com/StanislavLapitsky/SpringSOAProxy/blob/master/soa-integration/src/test/java/org/proxysoa/spring/controller/ServicesIntegrationTest.java) the source.

Comment: Thanks! It works. Instantiating 2 copies of Spring boot app and it runs with no problem.

Comment: One thing you may know. I'm trying to distinguish my running apps in traces and I'm stuck here. I was trying to add property like this - `"logging.pattern.level=App-1"` / `"logging.pattern.level=App-2"` but it always shows the one from the first  `SpringApplicationBuilder.properties`. Do you know why it happens and what is the right way for distinguishing?

Comment: Could be 2 things - logger is initialized before the config property is applied. OR property source has higher priority than the properties from the SpringApplicationBuilder. I saw somewhere order of sources which is used to retrieve values but cannot find now. Try to google.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. First app initializes its logger with property I give it with no problem. But second app ignores properties for logger. Furthermore, I investigated a bit and found that both applications use same `LoggerContext`. So first app initializes it with correct values from properties and second one sees that `LoggerContext` exists and do nothing.

Comment: I guess there are some static/singletons so JVM shared created instances. No Idea how to exclude this:( Just a workaround to include contextPath in logs to distinguish

Comment: Thank you @StanislavL. I've figured it out also. It is described here - [link](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/loggingSeparation.html) in **Context Selectors** section. So, I will stick to some workaroud.

Comment: @StanislavL what is "SOA.ControllerFactory.enforceProxyCreation"? Not much info in the internet. Also, I am trying to do the same thing for Spring Boot 2, but no matter what I do I restTemplate fails to "get" endpoint on an application. Though I can see that apps are running (the communicate with each other over a message queue), but when I try to do "get" I get Connection Refused.

Comment: `SOA.ControllerFactory.enforceProxyCreation` means need to create proxy no matter whether there is a locally available bean. It's just my own annotation. You can ignore

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work in all scenarios. Both applications you run will attempt to instantiate all AutoConfiguration classes defined in `spring.factories`. It's able to be worked around, but it's not an ideal scenario.

Comment: Hm. I get `Port 8080 is already in use exception`. It is set in `src/test/application.yml` and doesn't seem to be overridden.