# Starting multiple spring boot apps for testing

Tags: spring-boot

I'm referring to the answer here

[Instantiate multiple spring boot apps in test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47866954/instantiate-multiple-spring-boot-apps-in-test)

Whereby the test used a `SpringApplicationBuilder` to create and run the applications. eg.

```
@Test
public void testSomething() {
    SpringApplicationBuilder app1 = new SpringApplicationBuilder(com.app1.Application.class)
      .properties("server.port=8080");

    app1.run();

    SpringApplicationBuilder app2 = new SpringApplicationBuilder(com.app2.Application.class)
      .properties("server.port=8081");

    app2.run();
}
```

The problem I have is despite me setting the server port as per the properties above, as I have set the server port in my application.yml it seems to take this setting for both applications, and hence there is a port conflict. How could I solve this?

application.yml

```
server:
    ssl:
        ..stuff..
    port: 8443
```

Comment: Properties set with `SpringApplicationBuilder.properties(...)` have the lowest precedence, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config

Answer (score 1):

Don't set properties...use command line args with the run command:

```
SpringApplicationBuilder app1 = new SpringApplicationBuilder(com.app1.Application.class);

    app1.run("server.port=8080");

SpringApplicationBuilder app2 = new SpringApplicationBuilder(com.app2.Application.class);

    app2.run("server.port=8081");
```

Command line arguments take precedence over application properties. The result of this (of-course) is application properties are created just the same, but these will override any *existing* same properties.

Comment: Same thing I'm afraid

Comment: OK. Do you use the yml properties by their shortcut name in the actual application?  ie. _port_ rather than _server.port_?  You must match the property name as it is used in the app. Try _port_ rather than _server.port_ if you are unsure.

Comment: Nope it's definitely server: port: in the yml. Could it be because I have SSL enabled and the port in the yml is 8443? Both apps are apparently trying to start on 8443

Comment: Yes with SSL complicates things. Is it possible both apps are starting correctly, but are being redirected to the same port via your HTTPS config? Perhaps simplify and get working without SSL first, then get SSL working?

Comment: I did have port redirection enabled in my java config class but disabled it to see if that was the issue. Same result

Comment: Has to be a context related issue. Sounds as if both apps are running within the same context.